# Why including Rescuable module doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class MyKlass

  include ActiveSupport::Rescuable

  rescue_from Exception do
    return "rescued"
  end

  #other stuff
end
```

MyKlass is pure ruby object, but defined inside Rails application.

If I try to invoke MyKlass instance in rails console and then apply to it method which certainly should raise Exception, nothing happens other than error expected to be rescued.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469990/use-rescue-from-on-model-concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it should be used:

```
class MyKlass
  include ActiveSupport::Rescuable
  # define a method, which will do something for you, when exception is caught
  rescue_from Exception, with: :my_rescue

  def some_method(&block)
    yield
  rescue Exception => exception
    rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
  end

  # do whatever you want with exception, for example, write it to logs
  def my_rescue(exception)
    puts "Exception catched! #{exception.class}: #{exception.message}"
  end
end

MyKlass.new.some_method { 0 / 0 }
# Exception catched! ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
#=> true
```

It goes without saying, that rescuing `Exception` is a crime.

Comment: I though that the point of rescue_from is that I don't need to include rescue in each method. I have 20 of them

Comment: you can put a rescuing logic into one method which takes a block and than in every other method pass the whole logic as a parameter to this method. But this looks dirty and pointless. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567243/rescue-all-errors-of-a-specific-type-inside-a-module) for implementation details

Comment: congratulations you "catched" it :)